# Вид новости не такой, как в курсе, хотя код, вроде бы, такой же

Tags: html, django, bootstrap

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="media">
    {% if i.photo %}
    <img src="{{ i.photo.url }}" alt="" width="300" class="mr-3"> {% endif %}
    <div class="media-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ i.title }}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{ i.content }}</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Так должно выглядеть]

[image: Так выглядит у меня]

Comment: Версия Bootstrap'a какая на курсе и у Вас?

Comment: у меня 5, в курсе 4

Comment: В 5 версии вроде убрали `media`

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/28265

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#grid-and-layout

Comment: спасибо ::':'''